# Обработчик ошибок telegram bot

Tags: php, laravel, telegram-bot, telegram

Делаю телеграмм бота. Использую **laravel** и **[Telegram Bot SDK](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs)**. Сегодня столкнулся с проблемой, что бот рекурсивно отправлял пользователю один и тот же ответ [скриншот](http://joxi.ru/Y2LELvKsndPNRA). Либо просто сообщение 'Считаю'.

```
 \Telegram::sendMessage([
                    'chat_id' => $chatid,
                    'text' => "Считаю...",
                ]);

                $controller = $this->getReportControllerName($text);
                $method = $this->getReportMethodName($text);
                $report_data = new $controller();
                $report_data = $report_data->$method($chatid);

                try
                {
                    \Telegram::sendMessage([
                        'chat_id' => $chatid,
                        'text' => $report_data,
                    ]);
                }
                catch (TelegramResponseException $e)
                {
                    $errorData = $e->getResponseData();

                    if ($errorData['ok'] === false) {
                        \Telegram::sendMessage([
                            'chat_id' => '123456789',
                            'text'    => 'There was an error for a user. ' . $errorData['error_code'] . ' ' . $errorData['description'],
                        ]);
                    }
                }`
```

Блоки `try-catch` поставил уже после выявления проблемы. В логах присутствует 499 и 500 ошибки. Вопрос, по обработки ошибок, чтобы избежать спама от бота. Стоит ли в других местах отлавливать ошибки. Как можно логировать, в том числе код состояния сервера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никого не удивлю, наверное, но конечно стоит.

Для логирования используйте стандартный функционал от Laravel:

```
Log::emergency($message);
Log::alert($message);
Log::critical($message);
Log::error($message);
Log::warning($message);
Log::notice($message);
Log::info($message);
Log::debug($message);
```

А на счет логирования кода состояния сервера, вы сами выше написали, что просмотрели логи. Если вы имели ввиду онлайн, чтобы можно было быстро среагировать, посмотрите к примеру на https://www.statuscake.com

Answer (score 0):

Была такая проблема, что приходили одни и те же сообщения много раз без остановки когда вызывал метод sendMessage.

После вызова метода `sendMessage` в коде добавляю строки:

```
status_header( 200 );
die();
```

В чем смысл, если бот не получает в заголовке статус 200, он повторяет обращение с теми же данными, и так, пока ответ не будет 200.